# How to specify a parameter of type Array into a Django Command?

Tags: python, django, django-commands

It is straight forward creating a string parameter  such as `--test_email_address` below.

```
   class Command(BaseCommand):
        option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
            make_option('--test_email_address',
                        action='store',
                        type="string",
                        dest='test_email_address',
                        help="Specifies test email address."),
            make_option('--vpds',
                        action='store',
                        type='list',           /// ??? Throws exception
                        dest='vpds',
                        help="vpds list [,]"),
        )
```

But how can I define a list to be passed in? such as `[1, 3, 5]`

Comment: did you try just `list` - without the quotes ? From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type), it looks like `type` can be _any_ valid simple types. The other (hacky) way is to read the arguments as string, and parse it using `ast.literal_eval` or something.

Comment: yeah I tried without the quotes and its the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add a default value and change the action to `'append'`:

```
make_option('--vpds',
            action='append',
            default=[],
            dest='vpds',
            help="vpds list [,]"),
```

The usage is as follows:

```
python manage.py my_command --vpds arg1 --vpds arg2
```

Comment: sorry, thats an interesting idea, but it throws an exception: `optparse.OptionError: option --vpds: invalid option type: 'list'`

Comment: Removing `type='list'` fixes it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Can anyone point me out to better info on the `action` values? I'm looking [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#accepting-optional-arguments) without finding much info on what the available do or what values I can use

Comment: @domdambrogia the docs actually say to check https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action docs

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```py
        parser.add_argument(
            "--vpds",
            nargs="*",
            help="vpds list",
            default=[],
            type=int,
        )
```

The usage is as follows:

```bash
python manage.py my_command --vpds 1 3 5
```